# Attempting to add a "delete" button to existing "details" view

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, crud

I am working on a group project that allows users to create, store, edit, and delete notes.

We are able to access the stored notes via a very basic "details" view, and would like to make the "delete" functionality available within that details view without having to create a separate "delete" view.

As of right now, this is how our "details" handler looks in our controller:

```
    public String displayNoteDetails(Model model, @RequestParam int id, @RequestParam int userId) {

        Optional<SecretNote> result = noteRepository.findById(id);

        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("title", "Invalid Note ID: " + id);
            return "redirect:../";
        } else {
            SecretNote secretNote = result.get();
            model.addAttribute("title", secretNote.getName() + " Details");
            model.addAttribute("secretNote", secretNote);
        }
        return "notes/details";
    }
}
```

I was able to get a "delete" button to show up in the "details" view with the following:

```
<form th:action="delete" method="post" th:object="${secretNote}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="${secretNote.id}"/>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

However, when clicking on said "delete" button, it is redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/notes/delete`, presumably because of how I have the "delete" button set up. I'd like to add code to the `displayNoteDetails` that would allow me to use `noteRepository.deleteById(id);` and then redirect to `"notes/index"` (the user home page that displays all notes).

FWIW, here's how we had the delete handlers when we were planning on doing a separate view:

```
@GetMapping("delete")
    public String displayDeleteNoteForm(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam int userId) {
        noteRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "notes/index";
    }

    @PostMapping("delete")
    public String processDeleteNoteForm(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) int[] noteIds) {

        if (noteIds !=null) {
            for (int id : noteIds) {
                noteRepository.deleteById(id);
                model.addAttribute("delete");
            }
        }
        return "notes/index";

    }
```

Apologies in advance for formatting. I am clearly a novice.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<form th:action="delete" method="post" th:object="${secretNote}">
```

with:

```
<form th:action="@{/notes/{id}/delete(id=${secretNote.id})}" method="post" th:object="${secretNote}">
```

This will add the id of the note in the action URL of the form.